# Node js server read Authorization info from URL

Tags: node.js, authentication

I am developing a node js Server. The client is QT App which uses QNetworkRequest. Unfortunately the QT Client uses a third party lib to send GET request to server. So we are not able to modify request. The client send http GET request as:

```
http://user:password@127.0.0.1:17/sample_get_req
```

Node Js Server Code

```
app.get(SAMPLE_GET_REQ, function (req, res) {
console.log("req.credentials  "+JSON.stringify(req.credentials));
console.log("req.context  "+JSON.stringify(req.context));
console.log("req.destination   "+JSON.stringify(req.destination ));
console.log("req.url     "+JSON.stringify(req.url   ));
console.log("req.headers    "+JSON.stringify(req.headers  ));
console.log("req.body     "+JSON.stringify(req.body   ));

    res.status(200).end();
})
```

Logs:

```
req.credentials  undefined
req.context  undefined
req.destination   undefined
req.url     "/sample_get_req"
req.headers    {"host":"127.0.0.1:1729","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0","accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.5","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate","connection":"keep-alive","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","cache-control":"max-age=0"}
req.body     undefined
```

I already checked with [base-auth module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-auth) , but I understand the base-auth module looks for "Authorization" header in request. I checked the http GET request in Server, Authorization header info was not available.

How do I retrieve user and password from url in node js server?

Comment: If it uses the Authorization header, it doesn't guarantee that it uses Basic auth. I would inspect the actual headers to see what you're getting

Comment: Hi @Evert Added header info.

Comment: According to that, the client _does not_ send any authentication information. However, this client does not seem to be QNetworkRequest. It's initiated by firefox.

Comment: Yes, I was testing. This is from QT App req.headers {
 "connection": "Keep-Alive",
 "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
 "accept-language": "en-US,*",
 "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
 "host": "127.0.0.1:1729"
}

Comment: The URL used from both Mozilla and QT is http://user:password@127.0.0.1:1729/sample_get_req I was expecting that it should work with Mozilla. Is there any issue with Server?

Comment: That also doesn't have an authorization header then! It's not a problem in node, if you expected it to be there, it's probably a client-side problem.

Comment: Adding that username and password to the url doesn't mean it will automatically work. The client first probably needs to see what kind of authentication methods are supported. Also, setting the password in the url is now deprecated. You're no longer supposed to use it.